# XTS time subselect across DST date Linux vs Windows

Tags: r, xts

On Windows the following subselect code produces an incorrect XTS object, but works correctly on my Ubuntu machine

```
library(xts)
theTimes <- seq(from=as.POSIXct('2016-03-10 12:00:00 CDT'),
              to=as.POSIXct('2016-03-20 12:10:00 CDT'),by=60)

ExampleData <- xts(rep(1,length(theTimes)),theTimes)
CutExampleData <- ExampleData['T02:00/T16:00']
any(duplicated(index(CutExampleData)))  ## Evaluates to TRUE on windows (incorrect) and FALSE on Ubuntu (correctly)
```

SessionInfo on Linux PC:

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)
Running under: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] RMySQL_0.10.9 DBI_0.5-1     Quandl_2.8.0  xts_0.9-7     zoo_1.7-13   

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] httr_1.2.1      R6_2.1.3        tools_3.3.1     grid_3.3.1      jsonlite_1.0    lattice_0.20-33
```

SessionInfo on Windows PC:

```
R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 14393)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252 
[2] LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] xts_0.9-7  zoo_1.7-13

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] grid_3.3.2      lattice_0.20-34
```

I think this has to do with DST, since the index spans the recent switch over date.  Any ideas?

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output from `sessionInfo()` on both machines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to replicate this on my Windows machine.  It looks like an infelicity in `strptime` and/or `as.POSIXct.POSIXlt` between *nix and Windows versions of R. The problem manifests because your start time is 02:00:00, which doesn't exist on 2016-03-13 because times go from 01:59:59.999 to 03:00:00 in the America/Chicago timezone due to daylight saving time.

A work-around is to set your start time to *just before* 02:00:00.

```
library(xts)
theTimes <- seq(from=as.POSIXct('2016-03-12 00:00:00', tz="America/Chicago"),
                to=as.POSIXct('2016-03-14 23:00:00', tz="America/Chicago"), by=60)
ExampleData <- xts(rep(1,length(theTimes)),theTimes)
# 01:59 instead of 02:00 to avoid DST issue
CutExampleData <- ExampleData['T01:59/T16:00']
anyDuplicated(index(ExampleData))
anyDuplicated(index(CutExampleData))  # 0 (no duplicates)
```

Also note that "CDT" is not a good way to specify a timezone in R. The three-letter timezone abbreviations (aside from "GMT" and "UTC") may be ambiguous, so it's better to use the Region/City specification.

Comment: Thanks Josh...Looks like this works as a work around.  Any idea how difficult this would be to fix in R base ?  It's kind of a silly bug to have to always remember about.

Comment: @BNL: It would not be a trivial fix in base R. R does a lot of work to make datetime handling the same across operating systems, just take a look at any handful of the ~1300 lines of code in [datetime.c](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/datetime.c).  I plan to investigate further, check if this has already been reported, and possibly submit a patch.  I just don't have time for it right now.

Comment: You can see the issue by comparing `ISOdatetime(2016, 3, 13, 2, 0, 0, "")` on *nix (2016-03-13 01:00:00 CST) and Windows (NA).

Comment: Any update on a real fix for base R?  The issue crops up when cutting off data anytime between 2AM and 3AM.  So if you want to subselect anywhere inside there you are SOL on Windows

Comment: @BNL: I poked at this a bit, and I'm not certain it's a bug *in R*... the `NA` on Windows is because R uses its own internal timezone calculation functions, while the respective operating system timezone calculation functions are used on other platforms.  I like the `NA` result in this case because it indicates that something is wrong.  Whereas an output time of 0100 when the input is 0200 might give the false impression of correctness.

Comment: Any update on a possible fix for this bug?  I am seeing it crop up whenever I have a dataset which spans the daylight savings period and I need to subset out in that overlap.  Just moving it 1 minute earlier to 1:59 doesn't seem to fix it.